# How to uninstall the default screenshot app?

Tags: screenshot

I installed [Lightshot](http://prntscr.com) using Wine and PlayonLinux, and it works really well. But, I think the default screenshot app is interfering with Lightshot, with the actual prtscn button.

I was wondering if there was a way to uninstall it (meaning the default app) or at least set its hotkey to something different?

**Note: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, in case you need this information**

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screenshot
```

Alternately, open Software Center and type "gnome-screenshot" in the search box on the top right; then click Uninstall (or Remove).

Comment: The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome gnome-core gnome-screenshot
Do you think is it ok?

Comment: All you desktop will be REMOVED hahahah its my case when try do it in cinnamon xD, I only can disable keyboard shorcuts in my cinnamon and install other tool.